# Mcafee Commadline tool (vscl) takes long to load

Tags: command-line, process, antivirus, mcafee

Mcafee has a tool for command line scan, 
([McAfee VirusScan Command Line Scanner (VSCL)](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB75478))
In this page Mcafee tells how to use it, it's simple:

1. extract tool
2. download updates and extract it
3. run scan.exe /decompress
4. do scan ...

it works but every time it takes 1 min for loading!!!
I monitored its process and i found it check all Certificate registry keys (i guess for integrity checking) and writing driver files every time and ...

How can i speed up the 'Command line Scanning'?

Comment: Why are you asking us? Why not ask Mcafee?

Comment: Bcoz I don't know if what I'm experiencing is "normal" !

Comment: Most of questions that daily created could be asked by the vendors! but users prefer to ask here bcoz of fast, technical and practical reply!